# New to Magento 2 - Is it possible to change every product price every minute?

Tags: overrides, index, product-prices

I work in -precious metal industry- where item prices change every minute based on markets. At the basic level, UnitPrice=MarketPrice+Premiums per tier.

My questions are:

1. If we want to import MarketPrices to Magento, should we implement a visual cron job that runs every minute and retrieve market prices through REST API? I suppose this is the only way but I want to confirm.
2. If we override the functionality that calculates item unit price according to our price calculation logic (UnitPrice= MarketPrice + Premiums), do you see any issues with it, such as mysql indexes?  Is UnitPrice indexed in Magento2. Do you see any risks?

Thanks